# Преобразование строки в Unicode

Tags: php

Есть ли функция в PHP, которая из подобного:
"чтобы..."
делает
"&# x447;&# x442;&# x43e;&# x431;&# x44b;..."
(Тут с пробелами после #)
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

прочтите про htmlentities() и html_entity_decode(), они работают с html-сущностями:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 0):

Код. Вроде работает...

```
mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8' );
function orduni( $s ){
    $c = ord( $s );
    if( $c >= 128 ){
        $o = 0;
        if( $c < 224 ){ $b = 2; }elseif( $c < 240 ){ $b = 3; }elseif( $c < 248 ){ $b = 4; }
        $t = $c - 192 - ( $b > 2 ? 32 : 0 ) - ( $b > 3 ? 16 : 0 );
        for( $i = 2; $i <= $b; $i++ ){
            $o++;
            $v = ord( substr( $s, $o, 1 ) ) - 128;
            $t = $t * 64 + $v;
        }
        return $t;
    }
    return $c;
}
function html16( $s ){
    $l = mb_strlen( $s );
    $r = '';
    for( $i = 0; $i < $l; $i++ ){
        $r .= '&#' . orduni( mb_substr( $s, $i, 1 ) ) . ';';
    }
    return $r;
}
echo html16( 'Привет' );
```